# Transform nested arrays into same level as parent in mulesoft dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I would like to put nested information into 1 parent row. I am new to mulesoft and would appreciate guidance.

input:

```
{
    "number": 282,
    "topic": [
        {
            "fruit": "apple",
            "colour": "red",
            "quality": [
                {
                    "date": "2020-08-21",
                    "in": {
                        "feedback": "good",
                        "qty": "3"
                    },
                    "out": {
                        "feedback": "poor",
                        "qty": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-08-22",
                    "in": {
                        "feedback": "normal",
                        "qty": "0"
                    },
                    "out": {
                        "feedback": "good",
                        "qty": "2"
                    }
} ]}] }
```

output to csv:

```
"number", "fruit", "colour", "date", "feedback_in", "qty_in", "feedback_out", "qty_out"
"282",  "apple", "red", "2020-08-21", "good", "3", "poor", "1"
"282", "apple", "red", "2020-08-22", "normal", "0", "good", "2"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input**

```
{
    "number": 282,
    "topic": [
        {
            "fruit": "apple",
            "colour": "red",
            "quality": [
                {
                    "date": "2020-08-21",
                    "in": {
                        "feedback": "good",
                        "qty": "3"
                    },
                    "out": {
                        "feedback": "poor",
                        "qty": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-08-22",
                    "in": {
                        "feedback": "normal",
                        "qty": "0"
                    },
                    "out": {
                        "feedback": "good",
                        "qty": "2"
                    }
} ]},
{
            "fruit": "banana",
            "colour": "yellow"
} ] }
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

---
flatten(payload.topic map ((item) -> {
     temp: (if(sizeOf(item.quality)==0) [{}] else item.quality) default [{}] map {
     number: payload."number",
     fruit: item.fruit,
     colour: item.colour,    
      date:$."date" default "",
     feedback_in: $.in.feedback default "",
     qty_in: $.in.qty default "",
     feedback_out: $.out.feedback default "",
     qty_out: $.out.qty default ""
     }
}.temp))
```

**Output**

```
number,fruit,colour,date,feedback_in,qty_in,feedback_out,qty_out
282,apple,red,2020-08-21,good,3,poor,1
282,apple,red,2020-08-22,normal,0,good,2
282,banana,yellow,,,,,
```

Comment: Hi Salim, thanks again, this is good, but what i having is , "fruit": "banana",  "colour": "yellow", "quality": [], there is this 'quality' there but nothing inside. Output still same, hope you can help, thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to clearly give your input and expected output. Definitely cannot be asking 5 questions in the same question. Not just how Stackoverflow works.

Comment: My apologies on the messy information. Hope you can help to solve this question.

Comment: Updated the answer above to address your ask.

Comment: Please do select the answer as a solution to the problem so that it can help others in case they are looking for a solution to a similar problem. Ideally the answer should be Imtiaz's solution , though you kept on modifying your ask (another reason to not do so) in the same question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like below. If you are getting started with  Dataweave then DW playground is a great place to learn.
https://developer.mulesoft.com/learn/dataweave/

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
---
do {
     var id = payload.id
     var topic = payload.topic
     var password = payload.password
     ---
     payload.recording_files map ((item) -> {
         id: id,
         topic: topic,
         recordId: item.id,
         recordType: item.file_type,
         downloadUrl: item.download_url,
         password: password

     })
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. Can I check with you how to get each of the downloadurl and put in Request HTTP ?

Comment: If this is going to be your payload right before your http call, then you can use `for-each` and and  `payload.downloadUrl` in Http-Requestor's `url` field

Answer (score 1):

You should have asked the edited part as a new question. However the solution to your edited ask is below:

**Input**

```
{
    "number": 282,
    "topic": [
        {
            "fruit": "apple",
            "colour": "red",
            "quality": [
                {
                    "date": "2020-08-21",
                    "in": {
                        "feedback": "good",
                        "qty": "3"
                    },
                    "out": {
                        "feedback": "poor",
                        "qty": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-08-22",
                    "in": {
                        "feedback": "normal",
                        "qty": "0"
                    },
                    "out": {
                        "feedback": "good",
                        "qty": "2"
                    }
} ]}] }
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
---
payload.topic[0].quality map ({
     number: payload.number,
     fruit: payload.topic[0].fruit,
     colour: payload.topic[0].colour,
     date:$."date",
     feedback_in: $.in.feedback,
     qty_in: $.in.qty,
     feedback_out: $.out.feedback,
     qty_out: $.out.qty
     })
```

**Output**

```
number,fruit,colour,date,feedback_in,qty_in,feedback_out,qty_out
282,apple,red,2020-08-21,good,3,poor,1
282,apple,red,2020-08-22,normal,0,good,2
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. Can I check with you if there are more > 1 fruits in one csv? like for example banana. so output for banana will be eg. (additional row) 282, banana, yellow, 2021-09-12, good, 4, normal, 3

Comment: because currently the payload.topic[0].quality gives the row number to see, but i want see all fruits, instead of [0] for apple and [1] for banana

Answer (score 1):

**Input**

```
{
    "number": 282,
    "topic": [
        {
            "fruit": "apple",
            "colour": "red",
            "quality": [
                {
                    "date": "2020-08-21",
                    "in": {
                        "feedback": "good",
                        "qty": "3"
                    },
                    "out": {
                        "feedback": "poor",
                        "qty": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-08-22",
                    "in": {
                        "feedback": "normal",
                        "qty": "0"
                    },
                    "out": {
                        "feedback": "good",
                        "qty": "2"
                    }
} ]},
{
            "fruit": "banana",
            "colour": "yellow",
            "quality": [
                {
                    "date": "2020-09-01",
                    "in": {
                        "feedback": "better",
                        "qty": "2"
                    },
                    "out": {
                        "feedback": "ok",
                        "qty": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "date": "2021-01-02",
                    "in": {
                        "feedback": "bad",
                        "qty": "0"
                    },
                    "out": {
                        "feedback": "ugly",
                        "qty": "2"
                    }
} ]}] }
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
---
flatten(payload.topic map ((item) -> {
     temp: item.quality map {
     number: payload."number",
     fruit: item.fruit,
     colour: item.colour,    
      date:$."date",
     feedback_in: $.in.feedback,
     qty_in: $.in.qty,
     feedback_out: $.out.feedback,
     qty_out: $.out.qty
     }
}.temp))
```

**Output**

```
number,fruit,colour,date,feedback_in,qty_in,feedback_out,qty_out
282,apple,red,2020-08-21,good,3,poor,1
282,apple,red,2020-08-22,normal,0,good,2
282,banana,yellow,2020-09-01,better,2,ok,1
282,banana,yellow,2021-01-02,bad,0,ugly,2
```

Comment: Hi, thanks once again. If for example banana doesnt have 'quality' then it will not show banana row at all, is it possible to show banana row also? like  '282, banana, yellow, ,,,,' so if this no value for 'quality', it will show empty but still have the banana row. because using your above code, it wont have the banana row completely