# Sum with GroupBy in Nested Arrays in dataweave 2, Mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I would like to group by using the join_date and get the average qty (formulated by summing all in qty then divided by the number of records that have qty; do not take into account for those without qty).

**Input**

```
{
    "number": 282,
    "topic": [
        {
            "fruit": "apple",
            "colour": "red",
            "join_date": "today",
            "quality": [
                {
                    "date": "2020-08-21",
                    "in": {
                        "feedback": "good",
                        "qty": "3 qty"
                    },
                    "out": {
                        "feedback": "poor",
                        "qty": "1 qty"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-08-21",
                   "in" :{}
                },

                {
                    "date": "2020-08-22",
                    "in": {
                        "feedback": "normal",
                        "qty": "3 qty"
                    }
                } 

]},
{
            "fruit": "banana",
            "colour": "yellow",
            "join_date": "Yesterday",
            "quality": []
} ] }
```

Below is an example of intended output:

**Output**

```
number, fruit, colour, join_date, avginqty, avgoutqty
282, apple, red, today,  3 qty, 1 qty
282, banana, yellow, yesterday, ,
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the previous question that you had [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69154394/transform-nested-arrays-into-same-level-as-parent-in-mulesoft-dataweave/69181845?noredirect=1#comment122287105_69181845), there were a lot of ways in which the problem was solved which should have given you a fair enough idea to get started on how to attack the problem. With your question, input and expected output please do post in your attempt (DW script) at solving the problem and as to where you are stuck with the same.

You can also make use of the [playground](https://developer.mulesoft.com/learn/dataweave/) that comes along with tutorial to help you understand the usage in a better way.

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
import * from dw::core::Arrays
---
flatten(payload.topic  groupBy $.join_date mapObject ((item) -> {
     temp: (if(sizeOf(item.quality)==0) [{}] else item.quality) default [{}] map {
     number: payload."number",
     fruit: item.fruit[0],
     colour: item.colour[0],    
     join_date: item."join_date"[0] default "",
     avginqty: ((($.in..qty) sumBy ($ splitBy " ")[0])/(($.in..qty) countBy ($ splitBy " ")[0] as Number  > -1)) ++ " qty" default " ",
     avgoutqty: ((($.out..qty) sumBy ($ splitBy " ")[0])/(($.out..qty) countBy ($ splitBy " ")[0] as Number  > -1)) ++ " qty" default " ",
     }
}) pluck $)
```

**Output**

```
number,fruit,colour,join_date,avginqty,avgoutqty
282,apple,red,today,3 qty,1 qty
282,banana,yellow,Yesterday, ,
```

Answer (score 0):

Use groupBy function to group the records and filter to ignore all the qty less than zero.

[filter](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-filter)

[groupBy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-groupby)

The basic transformation is below, Please add groupBy and filter accordingly  -

```
    %dw 2.0
output application/csv
---
payload.topic[0].quality map ({
     number: payload.number,
     fruit: payload.topic[0].fruit,
     colour: payload.topic[0].colour,
     date:$."date",
     feedback_in: $.in.feedback,
     qty_in: $.in.qty,
     feedback_out: $.out.feedback,
     qty_out: $.out.qty
     })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).